# Joining two tables in MySQL with conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

first :

```
id_look     id_first    name
1           1           Jhon
2           2           Mark
3           3           Mike
```

Second

```
id     id_first     surnames
1      2            AAA
2      2            BBB
3      2            CCC
4      1            DDD
5      1            AAA
6      1            BBB
7      3            BBB
```

I want to get all `id_look` (same `id_first`) if surname is `AAA` AND `BBB`

So the result should be :

```
id_look
1
2
```

because only that `id_look` contains `AAA` AND `BBB` at the same time.

Comment: It's hard to follow your question.

Comment: If you could be a bit more specific...

Comment: So you want to select the id and id_first from table 2 where the id_first has both surnames AAA and BBB?

Comment: ``SELECT * FROM `Second` WHERE `surnames`="AAA" OR `surnames`="BBB"`` no?

Comment: He needs it to be both, not one or the other

Comment: Edit: Never mind, I see. I misunderstood his row placement.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT id_look
FROM   `first` f
       JOIN `second` s
         ON s.id_first = f.id_first
WHERE  surnames IN ( 'AAA', 'BBB' )
GROUP  BY id_look
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT surnames) = 2;
```

Comment: Cleane'n better, though you should backtick appropriately ;)

Comment: Works great in this scenerio but what about if in surname there will be numbers and I want to check if it is in range so for example I want to check if surname is > 20 and  < 50 and again if it is BBB

Comment: Ok I get it I can past just WHERE  surnames IN ( '20', '21' ... BIG THANK YOU !!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a little ugly, but it'll do what you're asking.

```
select id_look
from first
  inner join second as second_aaa
    on second_aaa.id_first = first.id_first
    and second_aaa.surnames = 'AAA'
  inner join second as second_bbb
    on second_bbb.id_first = first.id_first
    and second_bbb.surnames = 'BBB'
```

Comment: I shiver when I join the same table multiple times...  Hence, why I think it's ugly... :)  But, it does work...  The approach by Martin is a little bit more future proof, if we were to be adding 'CCC' and 'DDD' to the condition as well.